# Will Parallel.ForEach process in order with MaxDegreeOfParallelism=1?

Tags: c#, .net, parallel.foreach

Is `Parallel.ForEach()` with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism==1` guaranteed to process the input enumerable in-order?

If the answer is "no", is there a way to enforce this behavior?

Comment: That's a good question, and I would think the answer is yes based off of the docs. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism(v=vs.110).aspx   You could always spin up a a few test cases and verify.

Comment: Can I ask why you want to know this? Just academic curiosity, or are you experiencing some sort of real world issue?

Comment: @mituw16: I cannot find any hint on this in the linked MSDN article. Also spinning up a few tests is no guarantee for "yes".

Comment: Such question depends on implementation details and if it's not stated by msdn it can be changed in the future. Do you need to run something in order? Then use `Queue<>`.

Comment: @DR If you tell it to run with a value of 1, that would make it function like a normal foreach loop right? That would process the enumerable in whatever order the enumerable is.

Comment: @Sinatr: maybe it is stated in the MSDN and I haven't found it yet. Maybe there is a way to force the behavior?! It is not academic, in production the code should run with a different parallelism, but I want to have one test running with MaxDOP==1 and I want to know if it is guaranteed to process the elements in order in that situation.

Comment: when it comes to enforcing the in-order processing, you could look into PLINQ, doesn't guarantee in-order processing, but guarantees in order results. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460677(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If your test code requires in-order processing for something that isn't in-order under real circumstances then your test is flawed. Rewrite it so that verifying the outcome doesn't rely on this assumption, or rewrite the code under test to make an explicit exception when `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` is 1 so you are assured of its consistent behavior in all circumstances. The first option is preferable, obviously.

Comment: Interesting question! Maybe the answer can be found in the .NET source code? https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Parallel.cs,ecf3d8a35545d82b

Comment: What's the point of `Parallel.ForEach()` with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism==1`? This just seems like a waste of time

Comment: @l33t - looking at the source or running a test tells you nothing about future implementations. You need an _explicit_ statement in the docs.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, it is correct that [Microsoft's official documentation on parallel programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff963552.aspx) states that the **execution order is not guaranteed**.

> The Parallel.ForEach method does not guarantee the order of execution. Unlike a sequential ForEach loop, the incoming values aren't always processed in order.

It would be best to use `Parallel.ForEach` as the public API is designed: *to process items in a parallel manner*. If you need to process items sequentially, you're much better off using a regular `foreach` loop. The intent is clearer than using `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1`.

With that being said, for curiosity's sake, I took a look at the source code for .NET 4.7.1. The short answer is **yes, the items will be processed sequentially if `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1`**. However, you shouldn't rely on this for future implementations, because it may not always be this way.

1. Taking a look at [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Parallel.cs,d64f86dd50921f5b) and following it through, you'll eventually see that the collection to be iterated over is partitioned (this process is slightly different whether it is a `TSource[]`, `List<TSource>`, or an `IEnumerable<TSource>`.
2. `Task.SavedStateForNextReplica` and `Task.SavedStateFromPreviousReplica` are overridden in `ParallelForReplicaTask` in order to communicate state between tasks running in parallel. In this case, they are used to communicate which partition the task should iterate over.
3. Finally, let's take a look at [`Task.ExecuteSelfReplicating`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,b10f1afbb0308278). `ParallelForReplicatingTask` overrides `ShouldReplicate` based on the degree of parallelism specified as well as the task scheduler's `MaximumConcurrencyLevel`. So, this with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1` will only create a single child task. As such, this task will only operate over the single partition which was created.

So, to answer your question: as of writing, `Parallel.ForEach` with `MaxDegreeOfParallism = 1` will enumerate the collection [from beginning to end](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Parallel.cs,6cd8a40307748c3d) for a `TSource[]`, [from beginning to end](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Parallel.cs,9e0ecf73a270a93a) for an `IList<TSource>`, and [use `GetEnumerator`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Parallel.cs,38a83efeaf70c495) for an `IEnumerable<TSource>`, with slightly different paths depending on if the `IEnumerable<TSource>` can be cast to an `OrderablePartitioner<TSource>` or not. These three paths are determined in [`Parallel.ForEachWorker`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Parallel.cs,ecf3d8a35545d82b).

I strongly encourage you to browse through the source code on your own to see for yourself.

I hope this is able to answer your question, but it's really important to remember: **don't rely on this**. It is very possible that this implementation can change in the future.

Answer (score 4):

From MSDN:

> The Parallel.ForEach method does not guarantee the order of execution. Unlike a sequential ForEach loop, the incoming values aren't always processed in order.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff963552.aspx

Answer (score -1):

The answer is "no" but you can enforce the behavior using [AsOrdered()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.asordered?view=net-6.0) as shown below.

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

var items = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).ToArray();
Parallel.ForEach(items.AsParallel().AsOrdered(),
    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 },
    Console.WriteLine);
```

SharpLab sample [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgJgIwFgBQcAMACOSB0AMgJZQCOA3OlrkgKxVroBuAhmNscAKYC2AztgC82AKJQIvbmFYAjADbd8AJVZQA5twAUmADTYkmIwEp8AFQD2AQTAyAnluOMACu1bzF8/ADELYUawAxgAWWlx8/PhW/K4yHtzyjlH8APJgACbS3OmOuujYBdhQ3ADu2LHunikADsDEFlCCAN7YALKsAB4AItzqYNzcKQBmFfHyxPy8wgbYAL55aIW0AJxOQA=)

Obviously, if you increase `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` each parallel task will process its *chunk* (or *chunks*) of items - in the order they appear in the original *ordered* list.