# Parallel.ForEach and conditional with normal loop in .NET

Tags: .net, multithreading, performance, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

Will the following below do parallelism at 5 for 500 items, but a normal loop (no performance hit) with 1 item.  I dont want the performance hit of using Parallel, if there is one, when doing 1 item at a time.

```
 Parallel.ForEach(scheduledMatchups, new ParallelOptions
            {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = scheduledMatchups.Count() > 500 ? 5 : 1
            }, 
  gridItem =>
            {
// Process
});
```

Comment: What is the use case, are you looking for a general rule or do you have a specific peice of code that your are trying to optimise? Is the _normal_ load greater than or less than 500?

Comment: Have you considered to put this branching logic into a custom `Partitioner`?

Comment: I have no idea what a `Partitioner` would do.

Comment: @MikeFlynn With a custom `Partitioner` you can define how many chunks do you want to create from your data source. The `GetPartitions` returns with an `IList<IEnumerator<T>>`, which can  contain a single chunk if the elements is less than 500 or 5 chunks if there are more items. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-implement-a-partitioner-for-static-partitioning)

Answer (score 0):

You could refactor the action and loop sequence to have two distinct execution paths, whilst still only defining the *action* to perform once:

```
Action<GridItems> action = (gridItem) =>
{
    // Process
};

if (scheduledMatchups.Count < 500)
{
    scheduledMatchups.ForEach(action);
    // or for more control, you could iterate yourself
    // with a for or foreach and call the action() manually.
    //
    // foreach(var gridItem in scheduledMatchups) action(gridItem);
}
else
{
    Parallel.ForEach(scheduledMatchups, new ParallelOptions
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5
    }, action);
}
```

[This answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48832684/1690217) provides some insights into what else is going on inside `Parallel.ForEach`, if you are after ultimate control over the performance and implementation, then this simple branch logic still only defines the action once in a re-usable way.

> although technically there is an overhead, if you generally expect the parallel condition to be met, then the overheads are not usually significant enough to justify this type of work around just for the sake of it.

As pointed out by @Keith in the comments below, `Parallel.ForEach` is not going to, and neither is it designed to offer performance improvements for "Small loop bodies with a limited number of iterations". [This is covered in this article on concurrency and parallel programming.](http://abusanad.net/2016/06/25/insights-on-net-concurrency-parallel-programming/)

If your *action* is sufficiently light weight, then even with many iterations, you may be better off not processing in parallel at all.

---

I find it is often a better exercise to use `Parallel.ForEach` only when you can justify it for the type of action that you are performing. If the action itself was going to take some observable time to process, then for a limited number of operations the overhead is most likely going to be justifyable.

As with all questions like this, the real answer for your situation will always depend on a great many more factors than is practical to document here, so you should try the two styles of code, and determine for yourself if the impact either way is noticable or acceptable.

If you are observing issues one way or the other, please post about the specific observations. When choosing between parallel or not you should be cautious of *over* or *premature* optimization of a process that ultimately makes your code harder to read or maintain but offers little or no improvement to the actual runtime.

Comment: from the MS documentation in the anti patterns section "Small Loop Bodies with Few Iterations
You'll probably not get performance improvements if you use a parallel loop for very small loop bodies with only a limited number of data elements to process. In this case, the overhead required by the parallel loop itself will dominate the calculation. Simply changing every sequential for loop to Parallel.For will not necessarily produce good results."

Comment: I certainly wouldn't suggest making everything parallel @KeithNicholas I was more thinking that if you _sometimes_ wanted to process this particular list in parallel, you might as well always use parallel, if 99% of the time there is only a limited number of items in the list, make a specific code pathway for the 1%.

Comment: I'm more adding as info,  I'm all for profiling and finding actual problems, then solving with parallelism if needed

Comment: Thanks @KeithNicholas sounds like we're on the same page, I assumed too much the first time, re-wrote it make that point clear.

Comment: The problem is when I just process more then 5 items at a time out of say 900 items my CPU on my computer goes to 99%, that is not something I want.  If I have multiple customers doing this at the same time the that is an issue.

Comment: You might have to run it as a single process, not concurrently, in practise your code has to be designed specifically to function efficiently when running in parrallel. If it is CPU intensive then you should switch to a more horizontal scalable solution like using _EventHub_, _Event Grid_ or other _Service Bus_ or queue based implementations. Most of the time I see people trying to branch PLinq they focus on the parallel implementation, when it is the _Action_ that needs to be optimised first.